# How to install PyQt5 on Windows for Python 2?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt5

I am porting a Python 2 app which uses PyQt5 from Linux to Windows.

**Question**: How do I install PyQt5 on Windows?

What I have tried:

1. `pip install PyQt5` fails with:

   ```
   Downloading/unpacking PyQt5
     Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyQt5
   Cleaning up...
   No distributions at all found for PyQt5
   Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\user\pip\pip.log
   ```
2. Looking for a windows installer [on the official website](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download5), but there's only PyQt4 installer available for Python 2.

What do I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a very old question, but had I come across this question with a decent answer a week ago I would have found it very useful.  Here's what I did to achieve the desired outcome.  As you noted, there aren't supported packages for PyQt5 and Python 2.7 so you will have to build it yourself.  Thankfully the process is quite straightforward.  By assumption, you already have Python 2.7 installed.

1. You're going to need a valid installation of MS Visual C++.  I have the professional version but I assume that the community version will work too.
2. You're going to need to have an appropriate version of qt. If you're using 32 bit Python make sure that you get 32 bit Qt.  Also, (even though I think that it shouldn't matter), I made sure to get the version of Qt that was built with the same version of the MSVC compiler that I have. This could be important if there is any static linkage between the Qt install and PyQt (which could lead to getting a binary incompatibility of the linked object files.)  Get Qt from  http://download.qt.io/  Note that Qt has extra considerations around licensing, so you might want to take a look at https://www.qt.io/download/ first.
3. Make sure that the bin subdirectory of your Qt install is in your system path.
4. Get the source for SIP.  SIP is available from riverbankcomputing.com.  I used version 4.18.
5. There are three commands to build and install SIP.  Don't run these commands from a standard shell, use the Visual Studio tools command shell instead, so that your path includes the compiler, and also so that the INCLUDE, LIBS, and LIBPATH environment variables are set.

   `python configure.py`

   If you're using a virtual environment for Python you might have to modify the makefile for SIPLib since it hard codes dependencies on the location of the Python include subdirectory and the libs subdirectory. I chose to point them at the system Python install (c:\Python27\include and c:\Python27\libs.)  It should now be as simple as

   `nmake`

   `nmake install`

   The final part of this step is to check that the sip.exe program has been put in a location that is part of your path (this might only be a problem if you're using a virtual Python environment.  I copied the program to the scripts directory.)
6. Get the source for the version of PyQt that corresponds to the version of Qt that you got earlier.  It's available from the PyQt project on sourceforge, and the most recent version is available from riverbankcomputing.com.
7. Repeat the same process of:

   `python configure.py`

   `nmake`

   `nmake install`

   that you used to build SIP.  In this case, the number of makefiles that are generated is too large (all potentially with the wrong location of the python27.lib file and the headers, depending on your virtual environment.)  I just copied the python27.lib file to the location that the makefiles expect.  Similarly, there are three applications that are installed in a location that isn't part of the system path (pyuic5, pyrcc5 and pylupdate5) and I copied these to a location in the path as well.

Done.  You should be able to build your PyQt5/Python2.7 application.

Comment: Very helpful! Caveat: Using 64-bit Python 2.7, Qt/PyQt 5.7.1, sip 4.19, MSVC 2015 Community, I had to use "python configure.py --disable=QtNfc" for PyQt5, otherwise the build would fail. The same thing happened to other people: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2015-August/036222.html

Comment: Point 6 is wrong: PyQt5 does not sync versions with Qt5.

Comment: A year too late, but I'm marking this as accepted b/c I don't have access to windows anymore :)

Comment: `pip install python-qt5`  Thats it

Answer (score 27):

```
pip install python-qt5
```

Installs unofficial PyQt5 via PyPI for Python 2.7 64-bit on Windows

Github for this here: https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5

Comment: This question needs more thumbs up (y)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not coming with complete set, for example QWebEngine's QWebPage's runJavaScript function is not compiled with all three overloads, the callback is missing.

Answer (score 3):

There is an interesting guide about installing PyQt5 and SIP for Python2.7:
https://blog.synss.me/2018/how-to-install-pyqt5-for-python-27-on-windows/

To recall it, it requires to install first of all the pip and virtualenv modules to create a virtual environment for python where it will be installed. Then, it follows similarly to [Peter Du](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175555) answer. However, I would like to emphasize in the configuration options:

```
python configure.py ^
--confirm-license ^
--no-designer-plugin ^
--no-qml-plugin ^
--assume-shared ^
--disable=QtNfc ^
--qmake=C:\Qt\%_QTVERSION%\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe ^
--sip=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\sip.exe
```

In this case, remember that the Qt version should be similar to the version in PyQt.

Another point to highlight is the version. I have probed with the latest version of SIP 4.19.13 and PyQt5 5.11.3, however, even though I could install it correctly, I couldn't launch the module and import it as I have got a error  message related to a missing sip module, if using the developer console of Visual Studio, and missing DLL if using in a common console, as pointed out in [DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

I've tried also with the SIP 4.19.8 and PyQt5 5.10.1, as the example shown above, however, the PyQt5 in this version have some issues with the Community version of Visual Studio 2017.

Finally, I achieved to install it and launch successfully with SIP 4.19.13 and PyQt5 5.7.1 and Python 2.7.15, as commented by pixebeit in [Peter Du](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175555) answer, using Qt 5.7 (it is installed choosing this version in the list shown by the Qt Maintenance tool) and Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, with MSVC2015 as the compiler.

**NOTE:**

If you want to run standalone applications which uses PyQt5 installed by this method, from a conventional CMD, you have two options:

1. Copy DLL files from `C:\Qt\%_QTVERSION%\msvc2015\bin` to `%VIRTUALENV%\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5` if installed in a virtual environment or to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5` if installed in the base files, as pointed out in https://github.com/x64dbg/PyQt5.
2. Add `C:\Qt\%_QTVERSION%\msvc2015\bin` to the PATH environment variable for Windows.