# PyQt5 stuck on import, but no error message

Tags: python

I installed PyQt5 with conda this way: conda install -c inso pyqt5=5.6. I have python 3.5. When I run a simple program that uses PyQt5, the program gets stuck on PyQt5 import and there is no error message. It gets stuck for about 5 seconds, then the program just terminates. See the example below that I found on google. The program gets stuck on the line `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget`. I can see the packcage in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5. What might be causing suck a behavior?

```
"""
ZetCode PyQt5 tutorial 

In this example, we create a simple
window in PyQt5.

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: January 2015
"""

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QWidget()
w.resize(250, 150)
w.move(300, 300)
w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

First comment here solved my problem. [DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

I uninstalled pyqt5 and reinstalled wtih `conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/bpentz pyqt5`