# How to make a recursion loop function in python to loop through folders

Tags: python

```
DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def loop_folder(folder_name):

return 

def get_file_details(path):
     for files in os.listdir(DIR_PATH): 
      listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')  
    for entry in listOfFiles:
        if entry != '.DS_Store':
            if os.path.isdir(entry):
                  loop_folder()
            elif entry.endswith(".csv"):
                print entry
```

Hello, 
I want to write a script that loops in a folder and it's sub-folders until it finds a file with .csv and print it.

I want to make a recursion loop function and call it. But I am stuck and I could use some guidance 
My problem is with the loop function

Comment: just use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python recursive folder read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all `.csv` files in all sub-directories:
    import os

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".csv")]:
        #do stuff
```