# Visbrain PyQt5 import error

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using Windows 7, 64 bit version.

I am trying to implement Visbrain.

below is my situation.

I am using Python 3.6.
It is in my D.

I run below comment

```
pip install visbrain
```

It worked successfully.

I have a python script with only 1 line, which is

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

but it pops out this error when i run it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JamesTan\Desktop\test12.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

**Tried Solution :**

1. I check the contents in \Lib\site-packages.
   and see PyQT5 folder is inside.
2. Tried to `pip install PyQt5` but it told me that `requirement already satisfied`
3. Checked my PATH variable. It currently contains D:\Python36;D:\Python36\Scripts

I tried to include D:\Python36\Lib and D:\Python36\Lib\site-packages 
but it still pops up this error.

5) According to comment in this stackoverflow link :
[DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

5.1) i had python3.dll in my python.

6) tried to uninstall pyqt5 and install back, still appear this error.

Would like to know how to solve this issue ? Thank You.

===

**Solution**

According to this chinese link : https://blog.csdn.net/qq_41185868/article/details/80903095

it said that Incompatibilities with pyqt5 version and SIP version.
and it said that if sip version is 4.19.8, PyQt5 version have to be 5.10.1.

I tried to update sip to latest version by `pip install --upgrade sip`, so that my sip version is 4.19.8.

I tried was uninstalled PyQt5 by `pip uninstall pyqt5`, and installed 5.10.1 version by `pip install pyqt5==5.10.1`

Comment: Have you read [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)?

Comment: @FlyingTeller will refer to this, thank you.