# What is the difference between "ImportError: DLL load failed" and "ImportError: cannot import name"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The statement

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

yields `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`, but the statement

```
from PyQt5 import sdklfjsdlfkj
```

yields `ImportError: cannot import name 'dfgdfgdfg'`. This is confusing to me, because it's not like in the first snippet I'm trying to import something *from* `QtWidgets`. I mean, the `QWidgets` module is either there or it isn't, right? How is it possible that it's there "enough" to avoid a `cannot import name`, but also not there enough to be able to import it?

Comment: i could i magine PyQt5 isn't purely using python labraries but also c/c++, where it then says it needs the DLL when a c/c++ library is missing there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

Comment: @JonasWolff That actually did solve the larger problem I was having, so thanks, but still this question as written doesn't really have anything to do with PyQt.

Comment: so in 'from PyQt5 import sdklfjsdlfkj' your trying to import something which does not exist, in 'from PyQt5 import QtWidgets' you are indeed import an exsisting python module however it have to also use windows libraries/ c libraries, some those where not there, this leads to the message 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.'