# PyQt5 ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python-3.x, dll, pyqt5, importerror

I have tried probably everything and it did not work at all.
 This is my code:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QtWidgets, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication)

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton('Open', self)
        self.btn.move(0, 20)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        self.text_name = QLineEdit(self)
        self.text_name.move(100,22)
        self.text_name.setPlaceholderText("Enter your name:")

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 140)
        self.setWindowTitle("Input dialog example")

    def showDialog(self):
        text, result = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')
        if result == True:
            self.text_name.setText(str(text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pprint("input parameters = " + str(sys.argv))
    my_window = MyWindow()
    my_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the error:

[image: error]

I uninstalled and installed Python 3.7, I updated pip, I uninstalled and installed PyQt5 two times already. I have restarted my computer multiple times and still couldn't find a soultion.
Feel free to ask me anything that could help you solve my problem.

Comment: insert you code and error messages as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: There are multiple answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5 Including some that you didn't mention trying

Comment: I tried them before and none of those worked unfortunatley

Comment: Are you in a virtual enviroment? Did you verify that you have `Python3.dll` in the correct folder? Did you try to downgrade the version of PyQt?

Comment: ```C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37``` the python3.dll is in this folder. I dont have a virtual env and no i didnt try to downgrade the version of pyQt

Comment: I have downgraded the version now to 5.12 and it did not work.