# PyQt5 Converting .ui to .py file

Tags: pyqt5

I have trouble converting my .ui files to .py and the error message prompts out. Looked thru a few available sources on this site but to no avail. Anyone know what should I look out for?

```
C:\Users\SK\Desktop\ICT_project>C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyuic5.bat -x Northspine.ui -o Northspine.py
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\SK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Try to ```pip install --upgrade PyQt5``` , then ```pyuic5 -x Northspine.ui -o Northspine.py```.

Comment: The same area still persist

Comment: If you put ```from PyQt5 import QtCore``` in a single python file, does it run?

Comment: It doesnt run and prompted Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: I recommend you to ```pip uninstall PyQt5 ``` then reinstall. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5) can help.

Comment: I actually look into the link earlier to troubleshoot but however the same error still exist. I also tried sarting a new cmd prompt (hoping result might differ) but still the same.