# Having trouble trying to install spacy

Tags: python, pip, spacy

I'm trying to install spacy and I keep getting this import error.

```
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Users\Hebert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "E:\Users\Hebert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing nn_parser:
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possiblely relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5

Comment: @Brian I have installed PyQt5 to see if I would get the same error, and I had no problem importing it. I don't think it's the same issue.

Comment: Could you paste more of the console: the original install command & output etc ?

Comment: Thanks @SofieVL, I already have found a solution. The problem was the Visual Studio Build Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by installing Visual Studio build tools. I thought I had it installed but I only had Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution !