# Unable to import QtGui, QtWidgets modules of PyQt5/PySide in WinPE

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, winpe

I'm developing a tool to be used in WinPE and have been facing an issue while using PySide2/PyQt5 in WinPE environment.
While importing QtGui, it says `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified module could not be found.`
But importing QtCore is successful.
If I use the same environment in another Windows machine it is successful.

Answer (score 1):

I also developing a pyqt5 program run in winpe.
using pyinstaller convert it to exe and run successfully in a new win7 machchine.

when start at win10 pe the command line says below message.

> The specified module could not be found.

I found one solution is using specific version of PyQT5 from below url

```
pip install PyQT5==5.9
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51821319/7324168