# Pyqt5 "DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: The specified procedure could not be found." Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I came to the PyQt5 section from the Udemy python course today. But when I run the codes, ı get errors.

What should i do for fix this error?

[image: Error]

Comment: You should post code and error as text

Comment: But I reckon there's an answer to your question under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42863505/14316282)