# Msys update pyqt from version 5 to version 6

Tags: python, pyqt5, msys, pyqt6

```
Active code page: 1253

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MSYS /g
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt6
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt6-6.2.0-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt6-6.2.0-1

Total Installed Size:  23.19 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                     [#####################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                   [#####################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                        [#####################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                  [#####################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                [#####################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt6   [#####################] 100%

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MSYS /g
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt6-sip
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt6-sip-13.1.0-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyqt6-sip-13.1.0-1

Total Installed Size:  0.13 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                     [#####################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                   [#####################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                        [#####################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                  [#####################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                [#####################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pyq...  [#####################] 100%

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MSYS /g
$ python
Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug 15 2021, 14:49:43)  [GCC 10.3.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt6
>>> from PyQt6 import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Δεν ήταν δυνατό να εντοπιστεί η καθορισμένη διαδικασία.
>>> exit()

Χρήστος Παππάς@DESKTOP-8T1C1VF MSYS /g
```

I am trying to update to pyqt version from 5 to 6. But some dll is missing :(.
Can someone help me please?

Note: Translation of: `Δεν ήταν δυνατό να εντοπιστεί η καθορισμένη διαδικασία.` is `It is not possible to determine the determined process` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. First i follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5), but then and PyQt5 had the same problem so,
2. I run `pacman -Qqn | pacman -S -`  (updates all packages) from msys2 mingw64 bit terminal and the problem solved.

Hope that may be helpful for someone in the future.