# from PIL import Image - DLL load failed while importing _imaging

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm on windows 10 using Python 3.9.12 and pillow-9.3.0 and having some issues while trying to use
`from PIL import Image`.

Error i'm getting is:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could 
not be found.
```

How to resolve this?

reinstalled Python 3.9.12

tried installing / uninstalling multiple versions of Pillow :8.3.2 & 8.4 & 9.0 & 9.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

Answer (score 0):

Update your python version to `3.11`

Because `Pillow 3.9.0` was builted with `python 3.11 beta`

If you're using `chocolatey` as package manager use

```bash
$ choco upgrade python -y
```

If you're not using a package manager, download and install python from [official site](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: Updated to 3.11 and went with the latest Pillow, still gives error :"ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Try this instead 

- Upgrade pip and python
- Check python is added to PATH
- Try to downgrade pillow version to a previous one like 9.0.0

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your help, but 9.3.0. is the only pillow that works with python 3.11. But i have tried this multiple times, it doesn't work for me. But thanks anyway.