# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyqt5, pyqt4, labelimg

I get this error when I try to run labelimg on windows

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\okeon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\labelImg\labelImg.py", line 18, in 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\okeon\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\okeon\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\okeon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts\labelImg.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\okeon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\labelImg\labelImg.py", line 29, in 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'

Tried installing modules and imports based on errors, but nothing is working. Anyone with experience on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

Answer (score 0):

A walk around I discovered was to install labelimg and pyqt5 as packages in anaconda and launch labelimg from there. It worked for me