# Tensorflow connecting to gpu only in conda shell

Tags: tensorflow

I follwed [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) and was able to do this

(tf_gpupy310) PS C:\Users\micha> python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

showing that I was able to have TensorFlow access to my GPU.

however, in vs code, after making my interpreter Python 3.10.13 ('tf_gpupy310), and running this code
`import tensorflow as tf  print(tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support()) print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) print(tf.__version__)`

I get this...

2024-01-05 22:01:53.633573: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:53.633765: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
True
2024-01-05 22:01:54.740626: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:54.740988: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:54.741299: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:54.741576: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:54.741862: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:54.742152: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:54.742447: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:54.742744: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:01:54.742854: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
2.10.1
PS C:\Users\micha\Downloads\sldkfj> & C:/Users/micha/miniconda3/envs/tf_gpupy310/python.exe c:/Users/micha/Downloads/sldkfj/kldfj.py
2024-01-05 22:02:47.411103: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:47.411284: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
True
2024-01-05 22:02:48.501666: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:48.502061: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:48.502341: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:48.502563: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:48.502784: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:48.503000: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:48.503211: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:48.503418: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:02:48.503468: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
2.10.1
PS C:\Users\micha\Downloads\sldkfj> & C:/Users/micha/miniconda3/envs/tf_gpupy310/python.exe c:/Users/micha/Downloads/sldkfj/kldfj.py
2024-01-05 22:08:41.186517: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:41.186708: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
True
2024-01-05 22:08:42.236016: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:42.236378: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:42.236678: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:42.236909: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:42.237169: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:42.237483: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:42.237875: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:42.238209: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2024-01-05 22:08:42.238301: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
2.10.1

Comment: Looking at your error carefully, it has only DLL errors. I had a similar issue for a very different project; it was with Pycharm. I'm not too sure about VS Code, but in Pycharm I looked through the .idea folder (like shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5/75989327#75989327). In your case, try checking the ```.vscode``` folder.